# Animating the effect of changing kernel width in R

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing

I have some data in R, stored in a list. Think

```
d <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

although this is not my data. If I then enter the command

```
 plot(density(d, kernel="gaussian", width=1))
```

then I get the kernel probability density estimate, where the kernel is standard normal. If I replace 1 with other numbers, of course the picture changes.

What I would like to do is create a video or animation in which each frame is such a plot, but the bandwidth of the kernel varies from frame to frame, thereby showing the effect of changing the bandwidth. How can I do this?

(My apologies if this is not the right place to ask questions about R.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends a little bit on what your end goal is.

**Quick and dirty hack for real-time demonstrations**

Using `Sys.sleep(seconds)` in a loop where `seconds` indicates the number of seconds between frames is a viable option. You'll need to set the `xlim` and `ylim` parameters in your call to `plot` to make things behave as expected.

Here's some simple demonstration code.

```
# Just a quick test of Sys.sleep() animation

x <- seq(0,2*pi, by=0.01)
y <- sin(x)
n <- 5
pause <- 0.5

ybnds <- quantile(n*y, probs=c(0,1))
x11()

# Draw successively taller sinewaves with a gradually changing color
for( i in 1:n )
{
    plot(x, i*y, type="l", lwd=2, ylim=ybnds, col=topo.colors(2*n)[i])
    Sys.sleep(pause)
}
```

This works pretty well, especially using X-Windows as the windowing system. I've found that Mac's `quartz()` does not play nice, unfortunately.

**Animated GIFs**

If you need something that can be redistributed, posted on a webpage, etc., look at the `write.gif` function in the [caTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caTools/index.html) package. Displaying help on `write.gif` gives several nice examples, including a couple of animations—one with a quite nice example using the Mandelbrot set.

See also [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Graphics#Animated_plots) and [here](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=caTools%3aGIF).

**More fine-tuned control and fancier animations**

There is an [animation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html) package that looks pretty capable. I haven't used it myself, though, so I can't give any real recommendations either way.

I *have* seen a few good examples of output from this package and they look pretty nice. Perhaps one of the "highlights" is the ability to embed an animation in a PDF.

Comment: That seems to work. I am mostly looking for a quick and dirty hack to use for demonstrations in a class I'm teaching, but if I can post it on a webpage so much the better.

Comment: For quartz, it's faster to draw a white rectangle over the existing plot and then just redraw the lines.  See `tourr:animate_dist` for an example of this approach.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another approach:

```
library(TeachingDemos)

d <- c(1,2,3,4)

tmpfun <- function(width=1, kernel='gaussian'){
    plot(density(d, width=width, kernel=kernel))
}

tmplst <- list( width=list('slider', init=1, from=.5, to=5, resolution=.1),
    kernel=list('radiobuttons', init='gaussian', values=c('gaussian',
        "epanechnikov","rectangular","triangular","biweight","cosine",
        "optcosine")))

tkexamp( tmpfun, tmplst, plotloc='left' )
```

Answer (score 8):

One way to go is to use the excellent [animation](http://animation.yihui.name/animation%3astart) package by Yihui Xie. I uploaded a very simple example to my public dropbox account: [densityplot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6973449/RtmpeKvc2B/index.html) (I will remove this example in 3 days). Is this what you are looking for?

The animation was created using the following R code:

```
library(animation)
density.ani <- function(){
    i <- 1  
    d <- c(1,2,3,4) 
    while (i <= ani.options("nmax")) {
      plot(density(d, kernel="gaussian", bw = i), ylim = c(0, 0.25))
      ani.pause()
      i <- i + 1
    }
}

saveHTML({
par(mar = c(5, 4, 1, 0.5))
density.ani()
}, nmax = 30, title = "Changing kernel width")
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for the sake of completeness, if you need this for a class demonstration, I would also mention the `manipulate` package which comes with [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.org/). Note that this package is dependent on RStudio interface, so it won't work outside of it.

`manipulate` is quite cool because it allows to quickly create some sliders to manipulate any element in the plot. This would allow to do some easy and *real-time* demonstration in class.

```
manipulate(
  plot(density(1:10, bw)),
  bw = slider(0, 10, step = 0.1, initial = 1))
```

Other examples [here](http://www.rstudio.org/docs/advanced/manipulate)